# Is there available source code for the Ethereum parser (JS/Solidity or Python/Serpent?

Tags: evm, solidity, serpent, parser

I've tried looking at the source code, but I'm unfamiliar with the structure. I can't seem to find a parser module or source code. I'm attempting to understand the parser and perhaps write one from scratch (personal project). It would really help if there was source code for either of the parsers for Serpent or Solidity that could be found.

Comment: Which source code have you tried looking at?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the parser's source code in the ethereum/solidity project, it's written in C++.

Here's the main implementation file: [Parser.cpp](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/cc4b4f507784d67a7f53c5cbaee5a99fc6fe9e2d/libsolidity/parsing/Parser.cpp)

You can find the main repo where solidity is linked and which contains the required dependencies to build it in the [webthree-umbrella project](https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella) repo.

Here's a direct link to [the wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/wiki) for installing it, you don't need to install everything (qt is pretty big) if you want just solidity you can follow [this approach from the wiki (linux)](https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/wiki/Linux--Generic-Building#3-build-the-repos-for-the-project-you-want-to-build).